# How to open link in a fragment with webview when a specific item is clicked from listview fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have an Android app with a navigation drawer with menu items.This menu contains entry to multiple fragments. One of the fragments has a listview in it with names of websites. My aim is that whenever a name of website is clicked from that list the link associated with the listview item saved in stringarray in strings.xml file is opened in new fragment with webview which opens the site.

So far I have implemented this code for the fragment with listview

```
class AtlasListFragment extends android.support.v4.app.ListFragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.atlas_list_fragment, container, false);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),
            R.array.tut_titles, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}}
```

And the code which launches the fragment from navigation drawer is below

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment = null;
    if (id == R.id.home) {
        fragment = frag;
     else if (id == R.id.settings) {
        fragment=new Settings();

    } else if (id == R.id.about_us) {
        fragment=new AboutUc();
    }
    else if(id == R.id.atlas){
        fragment = new AtlasListFragment();
    }
    else{

    }


    if (fragment!=null)
    {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        ft.replace(R.id.fragmentview,fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By this mehod you can open a webview in where you want use WebView layout and use this method in your activity

```
public void openWebView(String url){   
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl(url);
}
```

Hope it works for you

Answer (score -1):

> ```
>  First of all you will need broadcast so you can send your clicked
>  URL from adapter to your fragment, and in your main fragment when you
>  receive the url you can use intent or webview
> ```

### 1- CREATE BroadcastHelper CLASS :

```
    public class BroadcastHelper {
         public static final String BROADCAST_EXTRA_METHOD_NAME = "INPUT_METHOD_CHANGED";
        public static final String ACTION_NAME = "hassan.hossam";
        private static final String UPDATE_LOCATION_METHOD = "updateLocation";


        public static void sendInform(Context context, String method) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(ACTION_NAME);
            intent.putExtra(BROADCAST_EXTRA_METHOD_NAME, method);
            try {
                context.sendBroadcast(intent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public static void sendInform(Context context, String method, Intent intent) {
            intent.setAction(ACTION_NAME);
            intent.putExtra(BROADCAST_EXTRA_METHOD_NAME, method);
            try {
                context.sendBroadcast(intent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

### 2- Send intent from your adapter

```
       holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent url = new Intent("url");
                url ("url_adapter",item.get(position).getURL());
                BroadcastHelper.sendInform(context,"url",url);
            }
        });
```

### 3- in your fragment this use :

```
    Receiver receiver;
    boolean isReciverRegistered = false;


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (receiver == null) {
            receiver = new Receiver();
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BroadcastHelper.ACTION_NAME);
            getActivity().registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
            isReciverRegistered = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (isReciverRegistered) {
            if (receiver != null)
                getActivity().unregisterReceiver(receiver);
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }


    private class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            Log.v("r", "receive " + arg1.getStringExtra(BroadcastHelper.BROADCAST_EXTRA_METHOD_NAME));
            String methodName = arg1.getStringExtra(BroadcastHelper.BROADCAST_EXTRA_METHOD_NAME);
            if (methodName != null && methodName.length() > 0) {
                Log.v("receive", methodName);
                switch (methodName) {

                    case "url":

                        String url_adapter = arg1.getStringExtra("url_adapter");
                        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        i.setData(Uri.parse(url_adapter));
                        startActivity(i);
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

> i hope this helped